# Which expression captures the following statement in predicate logic: "There are no more than two students who studied for the test."

Tags: logic

S(x) means x studied for the test.

∃x∃y∃z ( S(x)∧S(y)∧¬S(z) )

¬∃x∃y∃z ( S(x)∧S(y)∧S(z) )

∀x∀y∃z ( S(x)∧S(y)∧¬S(z) )

∀x∀y∀z ( S(x)∧S(y)∧¬S(z) )

¬∃x∃y∀z ( S(x)∧S(y)∧¬S(z) )

Comment: None, not even the 2nd one. Guess why.

Comment: If you are going to post a homework question or something that looks like it, you should share what you have tried to solve the problem and where you are stuck (not just post the statement of the question). Also, as Anne says, none of the options work

Comment: If you are going to post a homework question or something that looks like it, you should share what you have tried to solve the problem and where you are stuck (not just post the statement of the question)

Answer (score 0):

The second option is ALMOST correct. The reason why it is incorrect is that you also have to state EXPLICITLY in the predicate that x, y and z are all different from each other, as follows:

$\neg\exists x\exists y\exists z(x\not=y\land x\not=z \land y\not=z \land Px\land Py \land Pz)$

Equivalent to the above would also be a statement like:

$\forall x\forall y\forall z(x\not=y\land x\not=z \land y\not=z \implies \neg(Px\land Py \land Pz))$

Or:

$\forall x\forall y\forall z(Px\land Py \land Pz \implies x=y\lor x=z \lor y=z)$